# Azure Data Factory Copy Activity New Last Modified Column from Metadata

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am copying many files into one with ADF Copy Activity but I want to add a column and grab the Blob's Last modified date on the Metadata like the $$FILEPATH.
[image]

[image]

Is there an easy way to do that as I only see System Variables related to pipeline details etc.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-system-variables

Comment: I imagine you could use the GetMetaData activity to capture blob metadata, load that in to a variable, then use that variable as an expression. Like this except instead of using the value to call a stored proc you use it in additional columns https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/working-with-get-metadata-activity-in-azure-data-factory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Since the requirement is to add a column to each file where this column value is the `lastModified` date of that blob, we can iterate through each file, add column to it which has the current blob's `lastModified` date, copy it into a staging folder.
- From this staging folder, you can use final copy activity to where you merge all the files in this folder to a single file in the final destination folder.
- Look at the following demonstration. The following are my files in ADLS storage.

[image]

- I used `Get Metadata` to get the name of files in this container (final and output1 folders are created in later stages, so they won't affect the process).

[image]

- Using the return filenames as items (`@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems`) in the `for each` activity, I obtained the `lastModified` of each file using another `get metadata` activity inside the for each.

[image]

- The dataset of this `Get Metadata2` is configured as shown below:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bErm.png]

- Now I have copied these files into `output1` folder by adding an additional column where I gave the following dynamic content (`lastModified` from get metadata2)

```
@activity('Get Metadata2').output.lastModified
```

[image]

- Now you can use a final copy data activity after this foreach to merge these files into a single file into the `final` folder.

[image]

- The following is the final output for reference:

[image]

Comment: Thank you again for all your efforts in my ADF journey.  Is there a way to avoid step 1 for each loop? It sounds like it will be very slow if you have 200K files.

Comment: I don't think there is a better way without using for each. There are a few things that are main reason for this. We have different `lastModified` value for each file. These values can be retrieved using get metadata. Before merging, there is no way we can specify a condition (like adding an additional column with different value for each of the file data). Even to get the `lastModified` of each file, we need to use for each loop to proceed further. Therefore, there might be no other option than using a loop.